# A 'noun' defining a person who believes in 'luck' or 'time'?

Tags: word-request

I am in search of some term that defines a person who firmly believes in ***'luck' or 'time'*** (good time, bad time etc.). In other words, someone who thinks that all events happen in one's life is due to luck or time. You simply cannot change it.

There may not be one *single* term for it, but anything close will work. Do we have a *portmanteau* for it?

Again, my question is, I want a **noun** for a person who believes in 'luck' or 'time' *(I'm the one!)*. If you think that 'luck' and 'time' are entirely different, it's okay, get me a term for ***any of them***.

And yes, two words (hyphenated) are *okay* as far as they meet the requirement! Also, even if we don't have any term, how do I introduce myself as a firm 'luck-believer'?

Comment: A fortune worshiper?

Comment: I think you probably already know the word *superstitious*. Is it good for your purpose?

Comment: No. [superstition](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/superstition) is *the belief that particular events bring good or bad luck*. Here, I believe that *because of* luck, events happen -bad or good! Other way round... @DamkerngT. In other words, in superstition - events first, belief later...in my case, belief first and events later!

Comment: What about the person who is exactly opposite of a firm 'luck-believer' person?

Comment: Again, *optimist* comes close and yet doesn't satisfy all of your requirements.

Comment: This is related to [electional astrology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electional_astrology), perhaps?

Comment: **Determinist** - anyone who submits to the belief that they are powerless to change their destiny.

Comment: It is basically called *superstitious*, but *paranoid* can also be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fatalist comes close, though not completely accurate.

> [fatalism](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/fatalism) - *the belief that all events are determined by fate and, therefore, inevitable*

Check other definition for fatalism [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatalism) and destiny [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destiny).

Comment: I think **fatalism** is not the answer. Fatalism is about destiny, and when we talk about it, luck is on a different aspect. If something bad is **destined** to happen to a person, I will not think of it as bad luck as a fatalist, but just an occurrence provided by the flow of time and space (this is becoming metaphysical I know), something inevitable (good and bad luck **cannot** change it). Luck is about chances and decision-making goes with it still.

Comment: That's why I clearly stated "Fatalist comes close, though not completely accurate."  But this is the nearest to what he was looking for. A better single-word term may not actually exist.

Answer (score -2):

A believer of [Luckism](http://luckism.org/) is probably the answer.

From the source:

> THE ESSENCE OF LUCKISM
>
> Natural, unpredictable and uncontrollable chance is a fundamental part of life. It must be given more consideration in all actions than is presently the case. This leads to wisdom in coping with the challenges of life and promotes a healthy attitude towards the dominant world systems, including science, government, corporations and religion. Luckism balances the excessive demands of other systems and increases the likelihood that natural, harmonious and healthy actions will be taken in personal and public affairs.